# Перезапись файла c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

только начинаю программировать. Никак не могу доделать программу. Нужно написать программу, которая считывает английский текст из файла и записывает в другой
файл слова текста, начинающиеся и оканчивающиеся на гласные буквы, но пока получилось только выписывать слово которое начинается на гласную. Буду очень благодарен за ответ. P.S Обязательное условие по заданию - библиотека stdio.h, заранее спасибо :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning

(disable : 4996)
using namespace std;
 
 
 
bool vowel(char ch)
{
char a[] = "AEIOUYaeiouy";
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
if (ch == a[i])
return 1;
return 0;
}
 
 
 
bool end_of_word(char res)
{
char b[] = " \n,.;:!?)\"";
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(b); i++)
if (res == b[i])
return 1;
return 0;
}
 
 
 
void func(FILE* fin, FILE* fout)
{
char ch = ' ';
char res = ' ';
while (!feof(fin))
{
ch = getc(fin);
if (end_of_word(res) && vowel(ch))
{
res = '1';
while (!end_of_word(res))
{
putc(ch, fout);
ch = fgetc(fin);
res = ch;
}
fputs(" ", fout);
}
res = ch;
}
}
 
 
 
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
 
 
FILE* fin = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\дзшки 2 сем\\ОП\\lab_eight_c\\file1.txt", "r");
if (!fin)
{
cerr « "Файл file1.txt не удалось открыть!" « endl;
}
 
 
FILE* fout = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\дзшки 2 сем\\ОП\\lab_eight_c\\file2.txt", "w");
if (!fout)
{
cerr « "Файл file2.txt не удалось открыть!" « endl;
}
 
func(fin, fout);
 
cout « "В текстовый файл file2.txt были записаны обработанные данные из файла file1.txt" « endl « "То есть только слова, начинающиеся с гласной буквы (если таковые имелись)" « endl « "Конец работы программы" « endl;
 
 
fclose (fin);
fclose (fout);
 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
bool gl(char a)
{
    if (a == 97 || a == 65 || a == 101 || a == 69 || a == 105 || a == 73 || a == 111 || a == 79 || a == 117 || a == 85 || a == 121 || a == 89)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
bool check(string t)
{
    if ((gl(t[0]))&& (gl(t[t.size() - 1])))
    {
            return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream Q("abc.txt"); string t; ofstream Z("def.txt");
    while (!Q.eof())
    {
        Q >> t;
        if (check(t))
        {
            Z << t << endl;
        }
    } Q.close(); Z.close(); return INT16_MAX;
}
```

Comment: с выбором гласных букв решил очень плохим способом, буду признателен, если кто-нибудь решит изящнее